# Jenkins deprecated and warning plugins

Tags: jenkins-plugins, warnings, deprecated

After upgrading Jenkins to the jenkins/jenkins:2.394-jdk11 version I have some warnings and deprecated plugins. What is the best way to resolve this kind of issues.

1. Find Alternatives
2. Uninstall them
3. Downgrade Plugin
4. Replace the functionality with something maintained

## The following installed plugins are deprecated

JavaScript GUI Lib: jQuery bundles (jQuery and jQuery UI) plugin
JavaScript GUI Lib: ACE Editor bundle plugin
WMI Windows Agents Plugin
Async Http Client
JavaScript GUI Lib: Handlebars bundle plugin
JavaScript GUI Lib: Moment.js bundle plugin**

## Warnings have been published for the following currently installed components:

Project Inheritance Plugin 21.04.03
XSS vulnerability (no fix available)
Missing permission check (no fix available)
No fixes for these issues are available. It is recommended that you review the security advisory and apply mitigations if possible, or uninstall this plugin.**

x[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V8JVa.png)

I am trying to find best practice solution to my issue

Answer (score 1):

The best thing you can do is to either upgrade the plugins, or in cases where the plugins don't have updates, replace them with a better maintained plugin.

However, if you don't have plans to update your Jenkins instance and if the deprecated plugin still works on your Jenkins version, then this is something you don't have to worry about right now. As for the security warnings, if your Jenkins instance is inside a company network then you can probably ignore it since it is unlikely that an attacker from within your network will target your Jenkins instance. Under any case, it's not advisable to downgrade the entire Jenkins instance just so that you can make a plugin work since that will introduce new errors/vulnerabilities on other plugins.

If you don't use the plugins then obviously uninstall them.